# pre-processing notification data before user login in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to summarize latest updates (number of new emails since last login, number of new updates etc.) for all users regularly (say, every two hours). When they login to their account, these summary data is readily available, so I don't have to query for them from scratch.

Is there a gem for this purpose? Otherwise, how should I go about designing it or learn from previous examples?